# What is the phonetic reason for the occurence Sun and Moon letters in Arabic?

Tags: phonetics, phonology, pronunciation, arabic

In Arabic, letters (or more accurately phonemes) are categroised into two categories: [Sun letter and Moon letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_moon_letters) in regard to what happen if we add Al (the) to them.

Moon letters don't cause any change to the word's pronunciation. For example, Al-Qamar (the moon) is actually pronounced how it is written. However, in the case of a word like Al-Shams (the sun) the l is not pronounced and the consonant sh becomes a doubled consonant (pronounced twice).

I was wondering about the phonetic reason for that phenomenon. What makes a native speaker of Arabic do this? Are some letters faster to pronounce twice rather than pronouncing an L before them instead? Or is that due to another reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sun letters in Arabic are (or at least were in early Arabic) coronal consonants: t, d, ṭ, s, z etc., pronounced with the front part of the tongue touching the teeth or the roof of the mouth. In many styles of modern Arabic ج is also a coronal [dʒ], but in ancient Arabic it was probably more like [gʸ]; hence it is not a sun letter.

To describe this phenomenon as “assimilation” is not entirely correct, as it affects only the article. For example, you say at-tīn (with apparent assimilation of /lt/ > /tt/), but you also say iltizām, without assimilation of the same cluster. So it is not a purely phonological thing, but one that is morphologically conditioned. In other words: /lt/ is assimilated if /l/ is part of the article, but not assimilated if the /t/ is part of the reflexive infix in verbal morphology.

Similarly, there is no assimilation if the /l/ and the following letter if both are part of the root. E.g., you say as-sana (“the year”), but ʼalsina (plural of lisān “tongue”).

Comment: An important piece of the puzzle is that [l] is itself coronal; assimilation often works this way, starting with two sounds that are already somewhat similar and making them more similar.

Comment: @TKR: Yes, but what I am trying to say is that this "assimilation" is not a regular sound change, but is restricted to one single morpheme, the article. Thus, you are not going to find a purely phonological explanation for it.

Comment: Sure, I agree. Nevertheless it isn't random either: phonology and morphology are both needed to define it properly.

Comment: It only happen with definitive articles, اسم معرفه

Comment: It bewilders me why the assimilation doesn't always happen, but I believe this is worth another question. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Cyclone. I think the simplest formulation is that /l/ is assimilated to the following coronal, but this rule is superseded by the rule that the radical consonants (with the exception of /w/ and /y/) of any root are not subject to assimilation.

Comment: @fdb gives a good answer. But it's even more complicated. the /l/ in /iltazama/ may be sounded, but what about /inlazama/? Plus there are many examples in Quran and classical Arabic where assimilation crosses word boundaries. Plus, it's very likely that different dialects have always done things differently; remember that "Classical Arabic" is a fiction. What's fascinating is that Sibawayhi never attributed assimilation to rules, only to practice - "that's the way that Arabs talk", end of story.

Comment: @mobileink. Yes. In tajwīd /nl/ is assimilated to [ll], even across word boundaries.

Comment: @fdb: What is [gʸ]? Sorry I'm having trouble finding it

Comment: @Metamorphic. I meant a palatalised [g]. IPA should be [gʲ].

Answer (score 4):

This is a assimilation process. When pronouncing words like : al-nar `النار` pronouncing it as /al nâr/ would be hard and thus  they will pronounce it as /an nar/ these set of words are called coronal consonants meaning they are pronounced with the flexible front part of the tongue. In short it is done because it's easier to pronounce.

More on assimilation:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_%28phonology%29
- Ohala, J. J. (1990). The phonetics and phonology of aspects of assimilation. Papers in laboratory phonology, 1, 258-275.

More on arabic phonology:

- Al-Ani, S. H. (1970). Arabic phonology: An acoustical and physiological investigation (Vol. 61). Walter de Gruyter.
- Brame, M. K. (1970). Arabic phonology: implications for phonological theory and historical Semitic (Doctoral dissertation, Massachusetts Institute of Technology).
- Arabic Phonology and Script: An Introduction:
  University of Virginia, Oriental Languages, 1984 Writing, Arabic - 130 pages

Comment: If *al-tīn is “hard to pronounce” why is iltizām not hard to pronounce?

Comment: @fdb what is the second word? could you write the arabic word? /iltiznām/

Comment: التزام      ("Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" grrr)

Comment: /iltizām/   Starts with /i/  front, closed vowel. /at tin/ starts with /a/ open front vowel. Their place of articulation is different leading to different phonological rules.

Comment: BTW I'm not an expert in Arabic phonology and my IPA symbols might be incorrect.

Comment: ʼaltazimu ألتزم has /a/ before /lt/, for example. Place of articulation has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The pronunciation of this word is /at tazima/ you can listen to it here: https://translate.google.com/#ar/en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B2%D9%85

Comment: Not in classical Arabic العربية الفصحى

Comment: So what is the pronunciation in high arabic?

Comment: “I persist” is ʼaltazimu. “He persisted” is iltazama. I think the lady on "google translate" was trying to say the latter.

Comment: @AdelRahimi, do you have any concrete evidence that the sequence is hard to pronounce rather than hard to hear?

Comment: @user6726 the consonants are coronal consonants and /l/ is also coronal thus making it hard to pronounce. Also I don't personally like to call it assimilation more less a gemination.

Comment: I think one should be careful about saying that something is "hard to pronounce". English people have no difficulty saying "altitude" or "alternate".

Comment: @AdelRahimi, what fdb said. Most claims of "difficulty" turn out to not have to do with tricky articulatory sequences, they have to do with difficulty in acoustic parsing.

Comment: @fdb this is a dark /l/ altitude has light /l/.

Comment: @user6726 this is still not convincing for me. What is your proposal for the reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: @Adel Rahimi In Gulf Arabic, Al- is pronounced /ɪl/. Al-Tinnin (The dragon) is pronounce /ɪttɪnnin/, were in words that have /ɪl/ in the begining that is not the "the" /ɪl/ (in other words, the il is part of the word), the /l/ is pronounced, like in iltizam (commitment, /ɪltɪza:m/), which is strange considering that not pronouncing it would be easier according to the discussion.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier in my answer and in the comment for fdb's answer the process of assimilation in shamsi words only occurs when they are preceded by the definitive determiners not words that they have /al/ in beginning as their stem. It is because the /al/ in the definitive determiner is dark /l/ and it is hard to pronounce it with the dark /l/ and the shamsi word following it.

Comment: Another example in classical Arabic is the word أَلْسِنَة (tongues, al part of the word, not the definite article). Although the word has al followed by s, the l is still pronounced and the s is pronounced once.

Comment: The process I mentioned above includes fdb's answer as well (and thus agrees with it) also it's a more complete explanation of the phenomenon.

Comment: @Cyclone my dear السنه comes from لسان which has the /l/ in the beginning of it's stem, also السنه is plural form not a word with definitive article thus it should be pronounced. This is a proof for my words. As I mentioned earlier and I will explain again only of the /l/ is not part of the word and it is preceded by the definitive article it will be assimilated.

Comment: @Adel Rahimi I understand that only al in the definitive article will assimilate, causing the phenomenon in the question. I'm not trying to learn the language as I already speak it, so I'm not concerned with *when* does the assimilation happen, but rather my question is *why* does it happen before the definite article only? I'm just curious that if the claimed reason is easiness, why does the assimilation only happen when the definite article is attached to the word rather than always. When I say the l both in the definite article and in the example words I always pronounce them as light l.

Comment: In case you're a native speaker of Arabic, try to see if you feel the difference in "Allah", where the l is dark, and "Alsina" (tongues), where the l is light.

Comment: To my knowledge the reason behind this phenomenon is easier articulation. If anyone has a different view that rejects my answer I'll be more than happy to learn and to see my mistakes. Anyhow the difference between dark l and light l is subtle. To understand you can feel that when you are pronouncing /allah/ your tongue is a little bit further into your mouth though it might differ from people to people and/or different accents.

Comment: I see. The unclear reason why assimilation doesn't always occur is really interesting, but I guess discussing that will be better in a new question, as the answer to the question posted here was already provided. Thank you very much for your answer and the article suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The general phonologic process behind that phenomenon is called [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_%28phonology%29). Ease of pronunciation is the usual explanation of this process, but note that assimilation is always language dependent and not predictable (e.g., latin *octo* became *otto* in Italian, but not in the other Romance languages).