# Why does Laam sometimes get pronounced as the next letter in Arabic words?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, arabic, articles

I'm trying to learn how to read Arabic and I noticed that sometimes the letter Laam (ل) is either silent or takes the pronunciation of the following letter, as in this text from Wikipedia:

> As-salāmu ʿalaykum (Arabic: السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ‎ [asːaˈlaːmu ʕaˈlajkum]) is a
>   greeting in Arabic that means "peace be upon you".

To me it looks like "al-salamu ..." and not "as-salamu ...".

What is the general rule here?

Update: This question is similar to [another question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17339/what-is-the-phonetic-reason-for-the-occurence-sun-and-moon-letters-in-arabic) about "sun and moon letters". The body of that question answers this one, and builds upon it by asking the reason for the convention.

---

There seems to be little interest in reopening this question (which has already been answered to my satisfaction). I just wanted to reference my Meta Stack Exchange question that references this one and collects other examples of what I might consider "false duplicate" pairs: [When are questions which build upon each other considered duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312294/when-are-questions-which-build-upon-each-other-considered-duplicates)

Comment: I hope I clarified the difference between this question and the other. I would not / did not find the other question, with "sun and moon letters" in the title, by searching for "laam". I don't think that my question would be found redundant by users who do not already know what "sun and moon letters" are. That's the answer, not the question.

Comment: I think your question would be a better fit for https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com. I can migrate it for you if you prefer.

Comment: I don't mind having the question migrated, or closed for some other reason, as long as people can Google it. I *do* mind that people don't seem to understand the meaning of a duplicate question here. I might as well ask a question like "why are coronal consonants assimilated in some languages" and mark the "sun and moon letters" question as a duplicate of that one. They build on each other, they are not duplicates.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think this is a great SE website and it's been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /l/ of the definite article /al/ [assimilates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)) with the next consonant when that consonant is coronal. The affected consonants are /t θ d ð r z s ʃ sˤ dˤ tˤ ðˤ l n/ (the letter *jim* /dʒ/ is not included, because it was pronounced as /gʲ/ in Classical Arabic). They are called [sun letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_moon_letters) and the others are moon letters.

Comment: Although, in contemporary dialects, *jim* at least in the ʒ instantiation can be part of the trigger class.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_moon_letters), s is a "sun letter", and the "l" in the prefix "al-" therefore assimilates to it. The general rule is that if the initial letter of the word following "al-" is a "sun letter", the "al-" assimilates to it; for "moon letters", no such assimilation takes place.

(found by Google Search on "arabic language al assimilates to following consonant")